# Trying to transform delegate function to extension generics method with lambda

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

My intention is to... void Encrypt any property value in 'TSource', ***it could be all or some of properties depend on selector.***

This is my former code:

```
   ...IEnumerable<TSource>().ForEach(delegate(TSource ts)
                                  { 
                                    ts.prop0 = ts.prop0.Encrypt();
                                    ts.prop1 = ts.prop1.Encrypt();
                                    Etc...
                                  });
```

IEnumerable Extension :

```
...ForEach<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> action)
        {
            foreach (TSource item in source)
                action(item);
        }
```

string Extension :

```
...string Encrypt(this string strPlainText)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPlainText))
            return SomeClass.Encrypt(strPlainText);
        return strPlainText;
    }
```

**The point is how to transform all above into IEnumerable Extension just in line syntax,may or may not look like this:**

```
    //Encrypt all props. in Tsource.
   ...IEnumerable<TSource>().EncryptProp();  

    //Encrypt any prop. in Tsource. with selector property 
   ...IEnumerable<TSource>().EncryptProp(ts => ts.prop0);  
   ...IEnumerable<TSource>().EncryptProp(ts => ts.prop0,ts.prop1);  
   ...IEnumerable<TSource>().EncryptProp(ts => ts.prop0,ts.prop1,Etc...);
```

I'd be glad to take any suggestions.

Comment: @ColinE,  You've got my point but not of all

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell exactly how this could be done because you code sample is incomplete. However, from what I can understand, you have an `IEnumerable<TSource>` and you would like to perform the same operation for all of the properties for all of the items in this sequence?

This requires a couple of things, first look at [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx). This projects each element in the source to a new sequence, flattening them all into a single sequence.

The second thing is how to create an `IEnumerable<TResult>` from all of the properties of each element. This is not so easy! If your `Prop0`, `Prop1` could be stored as a dictionary that would help!

You could use reflection. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> source = ///your source
var allProperties = source.SelectMany(s =>
              typeof(MyType).GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetValue(s, null));
```

However, as strings are immutable, if you Encrypt the resulting sequence, your source `MyObject` instances will not reflect this change.

If you *really* want to do this, store your properties in a dictionary!

Comment: 1. Yes ,I would like to encrypt all "or some" of the "properties value" for all of the items in this sequence
2. No ,When I encrypt prop. by former code syntax, it reflect change to TSource, so encrypt the result sequence is not the goal!
Sincerely.